# Is it possible to configure tycho-surefire to run in the test phase?

Tags: maven, tycho, tycho-surefire-plugin

I haven't done a lot with Maven, but I understand the basics. We're using Tycho to build RCP plugins and I'm wondering why Tycho uses the `integration-test` phase to execute the tests in a bundle.

Is it possible to bind some types of tests to the `test` phase of Maven for Tycho instead of the `integration-test` phase?

If so, how?

Comment: It should be possible, can you show the relevant parts of your pom.xml?

Comment: @Behe: For Tycho users, it is pretty obvious that this question is about [Tycho's `eclipse-test-plugin` packaging type](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho/Packaging_Types#eclipse-test-plugin).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Tycho executes tests in an OSGi container, and this requires that the compiled classes are already packed as OSGi bundles. Packing only happens in the `package` phase, so the tests need to be executed later. Therefore, the `tycho-surefire-plugin` by default executes tests in the `integration-test` phase.

If you can run your tests as "JUnit Test" in Eclipse (instead of as "JUnit Plug-in Test"), then your code and none of your dependencies require an OSGi container. In this case, you may also be able to run the tests with the `maven-surefire-plugin`. This plugin by default runs in the `test` phase. I've found [this blog](http://mukis.de/pages/simple-junit-tests-with-tycho-and-surefire/) that describes the configuration which is necessary to do this.

Comment: Thank you, this makes sense. This leaves me with another question however. 

Does it matter whether you run unittests as plugin unittests (by that I mean let tycho execute them) or as regular unittests(let them be executed in the test phase without OSGi packaging)?

As in. Could I run unittests used to test code in a certain plugin, in the test phase, without that causing any trouble (in terms of not covering certain functionality or otherwise)?

I'll mark this as the answer. Though I would like to know if this can be done without side-effects.

Comment: This really depends on your code - but you can just try it out. If your tests still pass, then probably don't need OSGi.